# Rotate an image 180 degrees on click with jquery with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm making a drop down navigation and I would like to use an arrow that rotates to toggle it.

I have this https://jsfiddle.net/jaUJm/39/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$( ".toggle" ).click( function() {
    $("#image").css({'transform': 'rotate(-180deg)'});
});
});
```

I'm just not sure how to make it reset, as in, complete the rotation so it's pointing down again when it's clicked the second and subsequent times.

Maybe a .flip class with

`.flip { transform: rotate(-180deg);}`

and use an `if()` and `addClass()/removeCLass()`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

May change

```
$("#image").css({'transform': 'rotate(-180deg)'});
```

to

```
$("#image").toggleClass('flip');
```

Answer (score 19):

You can use [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $( ".toggle" ).click( function() {
        $("#image").toggleClass('flip');
    });
});
```

```css
#image {
  -moz-transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.flip {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="toggle" id="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/uLlPUfM.png"/>
```

Comment: notice that when using addClass, the animation only executes once. toggleClass can execute function infinitely.

Answer (score 5):

You already got the other answer regarding the `toggleClass`, but none of them explain the problem you have.

You successfully set the `transform` of the element to `-180deg` once you click, but your problem is that on the second click - you don't **add** another `-180deg` to that element. You only set (again) the value of `-180deg` to the `transform` attribute (which actually does nothing, because this you already have `-180deg` on that element).

You can fix this using the one of the other `toggleClass` examples (which would work great) and you can also check if the current value of `transform` is `none`, and if that's the case - set the `-180deg`, otherwise - reset it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".toggle" ).click( function() {
    console.log($("#image").css('transform'));
    if ($("#image").css('transform') == 'none') {
      $("#image").css({'transform': 'rotate(-180deg)'});
    } else {
      $("#image").css({'transform': ''});
    };
  });
});
```

```css
#image {
  -moz-transition: transform 1s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
}

.flip {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="toggle" id="image" src="https://i.imgur.com/uLlPUfM.png"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Find below the working code:

```
<!-- Image rotating by default -->
<div style="width:50%; margin:0 auto; text-align:center">
<h3>Image rotating by default</h3>
<img height="60" width="60" src="images/js.png" class="auto-rotation">
<img height="60" width="60" src="images/jquery.png" class="auto-rotation">
</div>
<!-- End Image rotating by default -->

<!-- Image rotation manually -->
<div style="width:50%; margin:0 auto; text-align:center">
<h3>Image rotation manually</h3>
<img height="60" width="60" src="images/js.png" class="auto-rotation2">
<img height="60" width="60" src="images/jquery.png" class="auto-rotation2">
<div><button id="start">Start Rotation</button> <button id="stop">Stop Rotation</button></div>
</div>
<!-- End Image rotation manually -->

<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jQueryRotate.js"></script>
<script>

$(function() {

// Image rotating by default
var angle = 0;
setInterval(function(){
angle+=2;
$(".auto-rotation").rotate(angle);
},10);


// Image rotation manually
var ang = 0;
$("#start").click(function() {

window.st = setInterval(function(){
   ang+=4;
   $(".auto-rotation2").rotate(ang);
   },10);
});

$("#stop").click(function() {
clearInterval(window.st);
});
// End Example-3

});

</script>
```

For detailed working demo code [click here](https://www.quora.com/How-can-you-rotate-images-using-JavaScript/answer/Pankaj-Kumar-3715)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow!  We love explanations here.  Could you suggest one for this code?

Answer (score 0):

Just use this easy method!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".toggle" ).click( function() {
    console.log($("#img").css('transform'));
    if ($("#img").css('transform') == 'none') {
      $("#img").css({'transform': 'rotate(-180deg)'});
    } else {
      $("#img").css({'transform': ''});
    };
  });
});
```

```css
#img {
  -moz-transition: transform 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.flippingImage {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="toggle" id="img" src="https://i.imgur.com/uLlPUfM.png"/>
```